# CallDirectory - How to have dynamic label text for a phone number

Tags: ios, callkit, incoming-call

I have a below requirement and I need your valuable suggestions and solutions.

Requirement :

Whenever I get a call from one particular number, I need to make a API call and get  some info and need to display it along with Caller ID as label text.

Kindly suggest is the requirement can be achieved, if so please guide me with the solution.

I am following below steps :

1. Created CallDirectoryExtension and added the particular number with
   some label.
2. Turned on Call identification and blocking
3. Whenever I make a call [App Name] Called ID: [Label] is getting
   displayed instead of Unknown.
4. To identify the incoming call I am using CXCallObserver and public
   func callObserver(_ callObserver: CXCallObserver, callChanged call:
   CXCall) method.
5. Calling the required API and saving the data in Userdefaults under
   app group.
6. Calling CXCallDirectoryManager.sharedInstance
   .reloadExtension(withIdentifier:
   "com.example.Sample.SampleDirectory") to re-execute
   CXCallDirectoryProvider's method override func beginRequest(with
   context: CXCallDirectoryExtensionContext)
   context.addIdentificationEntry(withNextSequentialPhoneNumber:
   phoneNumber, label: label) is getting executed with new changed
   label by getting it from app group use defaults.
7. But in the caller screen the label is not getting updated.

Kindly suggest how can i change the label (calling an API and getting some details, that i am setting as updated label), when there is incoming call.

Answer (score 0):

What you request is not supported by CallDirectory Extension. On the contrary all phone numbers that you want to identify/block **must be provided beforehand** in order to be matched and identified by the OS.

That means that when phone rings, if the number is not matched from user's contacts, then the OS queries the CallDirectory Extension. If **phone is already added**, then it is matched.

From what I understand by your impelementation, you will get the updated label, but for consequent incoming calls (maybe), but definitely not the current one.